# Add Button On Safari And Execute Shell Command On button Click

Tags: objective-c, shell, safari, xcode4.2, safari-extension

I want to run a shell command from Button on Safari Browser. I have successfully added the button on safari browser using Safari Extension Program. Using that button I'm able to open a website in new tab. basically I want to use that button to run a tool on mac.

I have developed an mac application and want to run this application from the button on that safari browser. For that I need to run a shell command from the button.

Please help me I'm new in mac development and safari extension. My first question is:  Is it possible to run a application on mac from the button on safari browser ?
If its possible am I join in right direction to execute that application from shell command which is run on button click ?

Is there any other way to do the same ?

Please help me . Thanks in advance.

Comment: The 1Password extension does something like this. Extensions are very limited in what they can do, and apps are completely sandboxed as well these days. I believe the best solution is probably for the app to run a WebSocket server, then the browser extension can act as a client that communicates with it. Or a simple HTTP server with AJAX communication might be easier.

Comment: I tried this by using node.js . I created a server code in node.js which start the server and runs command to start the mac tool. then i call this server from browser and i am  able to do the same .   But problem is still same i need to start the the server first by using shell command after that this all work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a server in node.js script and insert the code in it to run the command( to run that tool). Now call this url from button that you have added in safari browser.

Not very sure but may be use full for you.